# How to associate new "aws_wafregional_rule" with existing WAF ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-waf

I have created a WAF ACL using AWS Console. Now I need to create WAF Rule using Terraform, so I have implemented below rule.

```
resource "aws_wafregional_byte_match_set" "blocked_path_match_set" {
  name = format("%s-%s-blocked-path", local.name, var.module)

  dynamic "byte_match_tuples" {
    for_each = length(var.blocked_path_prefixes) > 0 ? var.blocked_path_prefixes : []

    content {
      field_to_match {
        type = lookup(byte_match_tuples.value, "type", null)
      }
      target_string         = lookup(byte_match_tuples.value, "target_string", null)
      positional_constraint = lookup(byte_match_tuples.value, "positional_constraint", null)
      text_transformation   = lookup(byte_match_tuples.value, "text_transformation", null)
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_wafregional_rule" "blocked_path_allowed_ipaccess" {
  metric_name = format("%s%s%sBlockedPathIpaccess", var.application, var.environment, var.module)
  name        = format("%s%s%sBlockedPathIpaccessRule", var.application, var.environment, var.module)

  predicate {
    type    = "ByteMatch"
    data_id = aws_wafregional_byte_match_set.blocked_path_match_set.id
    negated = false
  }
}
```

But how do I map this new rule to existing "web_acl" which was created through AWS Console. As per documentation I can use "aws_wafregional_web_acl" to create new web_acl, but is there a way to associate rule created through terraform with existing waf_acl ? I have a gitlab pipeline which deploys terraform code to aws, so eventually I will pass id/arn of existing web_acl and through pipeline just add/update new rule without impacting existing rules which were created through console.

Please share your valuable feedback.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the WAF documentation you associate the rule via an AWS WAF resource, see the example below for a code snippet.

```
resource "aws_wafregional_web_acl" "foo" {
  name        = "foo"
  metric_name = "foo"

  default_action {
    type = "ALLOW"
  }

  rule {
    action {
      type = "BLOCK"
    }

    priority = 1
    rule_id  = aws_wafregional_rule.blocked_path_allowed_ipaccess.id
  }
}
```

However, as you said you have created the resource already in the AWS console. Terraform does support the [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) of an AWS resource, so you would need to go with this method if you would like to manage it via Terraform.

Comment: Chris, Thank you for your inputs. I tried what you suggested by importing "aws_wafregional_web_acl" using "terraform import". But what happens is when I try to add new rules it deletes existing rule which were already associated to "aws_wafregional_web_acl" while creating through console. I need to keep existing rules as is and just add 2 additional rules through terraform. Please let me know your inputs. Thank you.

Comment: Ah I see you have rules already, I believe you'll need to add 2 more `rule` blocks inside the `aws_wafregional_web_acl` that match the rules already existing